# Different resolution in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have layout with two Plain Text. This is code:

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextName"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
            android:hint="Förnamn"
             >

        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextAdress"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextName"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editTextName"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" 
            android:hint="Gatuadress">


        </EditText>
```

I have a problem with resolution. When I use emulator in 3,7in looks great but when I change on 10.1in(tablet) my Plain texts are very small. How I can do that in every relolution my Plain Texts looks the same?

This is photos for better understanding:

[image]

[image]

I want to this Plain text looks the same on resolution for tablets and smaller screens.

Comment: EditText looks small or typing text inside EditText looks small ?

Comment: EditText looks small. I want to this two EditText on picture 2 looks like on the picture 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the text size using sp:

```
android:textSize="20sp"
```

This page explains how to handle multiple resolutions, and also what the sp units are and how they work:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Yes it does, that's exactly what it does. It makes sure the text is scaled depending on the screen density of the device. If you don't think so, then you need to define what you mean by "won't work the same" which is vague in terms of exactly what the problem is.

Comment: You've scaled the 10.1" screenshot down to the same size as the 3.7" device, which is why it appears smaller. The sp units mean the dimensions of the EditText will be about the same physical size (e.g. 10mm) on all devices. If you want huge text boxes on a tablet, then you need to use separate resources in the resources folder for those different sized devices. I'd say the approach you're taking is not a good one though - there's no need for huge EditText fields on a  tablet.

Comment: Yes that's the problem. Most of phones is hdpi, and most of tablets is mdpi, so if you use the same sp value for text size, if the text looks normally on phone, it will look quite small on tablet. That's what I mean "won't work the same way"

Comment: I don't see a problem with that. If a button is 1cm high on a phone, why does it need to be 2cm or 3cm on a tablet? Most often it doesn't. If it does, then you need to create separate layouts for different sized screens and put them in the relevant layout folder. Read the page I posted, it explains how this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
android:textSize="15sp"
```

to set the text size of a textview, should hopefully render to approximately the same size on all devices.